# How to use an if condition to filter JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I am working on a REST API, and I have a JSON file which has lots of values. I want to check for a specific category, and when I find that category the loop will break and content will show for that particular category. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SuperDeal.com Baap of all deals</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/…/li…/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Boostarp -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />
    <!-- Boostrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/custom.css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!--header section -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SuperDeal.com </a>
            </div>
            <!-- menu section -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="# ">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="# ">Register and win </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Conatct Us </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <?php
$ch = curl_init("http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php…"); // add your url which contains json file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
//print_R($json);
$count=count($json);
echo'<table class="table"><th>BlueStone Offers</th><th>Link</th>';
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    if ($json[$i]['offer_name']=='Bluestone.com CPS - India'){
        echo'<tr><td>'.$json[$i]['offer_name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$json[$i]['coupon_title'].'</td>
        <td>'.$json[$i]['coupon_code'].'</td>
        <td bgcolor="yellow"><a href='.$json[$i]['link'].'> Grap The Deal </a></td>
        </tr>';
        echo'</table>';
    }
    break;
}

?>
<?php
echo substr("Koovs.com CPS - India",6);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

… I am trying to populate the “Bluestone Offers” HTML table with only the relevant entries contained in the JSON response. I am inspecting the `offer_name` field for a specific string value (“Bluestone.com CPS - India”, as above).

Comment: How is this not working for you currently? Are you getting some kind of error, or is the program just behaving in an unexpected way?

Comment: i am not getting any error as you see i want to show records from certain category so in this i check the if condition within the for loop but i dont get my results .

Comment: Added clarification about what the code is apparently trying to accomplish

Comment: Your `break` is going to happen on the first iteration of the loop no matter what. Don't you want it inside the `if` block?

Comment: If you run `var_dump($json[$i]['offer_name'], $json[$i]['offer_name'] == 'Bluestone.com CPS - India', trim($json[$i]['offer_name']) == 'Bluestone.com CPS - India')` what you get in response?

Comment: problem solved thanks for support